# Prepend a timestamp to Shell output in CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

What is the cleanest way to have a timestamp prepended to Shell output in a CakePHP 3 Shell?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "clean", and whether you'd want to prepend it to _everything_, ie also to horizontal lines, empty lines, tables, progress bars, etc...

Comment: @ndm By clean I mean not overriding e.g. `Shell::out()` and prepending the timestamp. It should only be prepended to plain text output.